# UIImageNamed -> get asset by size class

Tags: ios, ipad, uiimage, size-classes

I am trying to retrive an asset from the image catalogue, according to size class.
This is how the assets are organized in the images catalogue:

[image]

When I do:

```
UIImage *addTaskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"big_add_plus_new"];
```

and the iPad is on 1/3 screen, I always get the upper image ([**]).

("big_add_plus_new" is the name of the set)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: And what did you expect? Remember that screen(or part of it avaiable to your app) size doesn't actually matter as far as assets are concerned, but rather its density - i.e. if it is Retina HD(@3x), Retina (@2x) or a "plain" screen (@1x).

Comment: [-*] image should be loaded in Compact width on iPad.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `init(named:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection:)` method of a `UIImage`

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:inBundle:compatibleWithTraitCollection: